# How to validate using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

My Requirement is that 
My first two digits in entered number is of the range 00-32..
How can i check this through regex in C#?
I could not Figure it out !!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need a regex?

```
int val;
if (Int32.TryParse("00ABFSSDF".Substring(0, 2), out val))
{
    if (val >= 0 && val <= 32)
    {
        // valid
    }
}
```

Comment: But I should Check they are in the range 00-32 na?How can I do that ?Without Regex if it possible also I am ready to implement that...

Comment: @VigneshMurugan yeah I just realised you asked that, thought you were only interested in them being `int`. I have updated for validation.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is almost certainly a learning exercise, here are some hints:

- Your rexex will be an "OR" `|` of two parts, both validating the first two characters
- The first expression part will match if the first character is a digit is 0..2, and the second character is a digit 0..9
- The second expression part will match if the first character is digit `3`, and the second character is a digit `0..2`

To match a range of digits, use `[A-B]` range, where `A` is the lower and `B` is the upper bound for the digits to match (both bounds are inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-2])$");
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch("00"));
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch("22"));
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch("33"));
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch("42"));
```

The `[0-2]?[0-9]` matches all numbers from zero to 29 and the `3[0-2]` matches 30-32.

This will validate number from 0 to 32, and also allows for numbers with leading zero, eg, 08.

Answer (score 1):

You should divide the region as in:

```
^[012]\d|3[012]
```

Comment: That's much better :) You do not need to keep the incorrect part of the answer visible - the edit history would keep it for the curious ones, while the rest should see a nice and clean answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("123456789","^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-2])"))
    // match
```